# External login username with Google+ and Asp.Net Identty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-plus, owin

Google+ returns the name and last name as the username using Owin in Asp.Net

This can contain special characters (accents, etc...) so when trying to create a user using that username it throws an error.

Question: What's the best way to handle usernames with special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options. If you actually want to allow the special characters as part of the username (a good idea if this is going to be an application with an international user-base), then you can simply disable the alphanumeric-only validation. Just add the following in your controller (where `UserManager` is defined):

```
UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User>(UserManager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
```

If you don't care about keeping the diacritics (the accents and such that make the characters "special"), then you can strip them out and replace them with an ASCII representation. I have the following method I use to generate slugs:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string s)
    {
        s = s ?? string.Empty;
        if (s.Length > 0)
        {
            char[] chars = new char[s.Length];
            int charIndex = 0;

            s = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                char c = s[i];
                if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                    chars[charIndex++] = c;
            }

            return new string(chars, 0, charIndex).Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```